# Insert Data of a Table into an Input Field inside a Modal

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with data inside. Every row contains a button that allows to modify that item and send a Put request.
I want to populate the form with the data of the row selected, so changes can be made a lot easier.
**This is the modal**

```html
<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body-modify">
  <label for="Name">Name:</label>               <input id="NamePut" type="text" name="Name">
  <label for="Surname">Surname:</label>         <input id="SurnamePut" type="text" name="Surname">
  <label for="Birthday">Birthday:</label>       <input id="BirthdayPut" type="text" name="Birthday">
  <label for="Fiscal-Code">Fiscal Code:</label> <input id="Fiscal-CodePut" type="text" name="Fiscal-Code">
  <label for="Course">Course:</label>
  <select id="CourseSelectPut" name="Course">
    <option class="optionPut" value="nessuno" selected>nobody</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onclick="eliminaMessaggioPut()">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Put()" id="modalModificaButton">Modify</button>
</div>
```

Normally, to take data from that table and write it on my page I do this:

```
var name           = document.getElementById(`name-${id}`);
var surname        = document.getElementById(`surname-${id}`);
var divTitle       = document.getElementById("nomeStudente");
divTitle.innerText = name.innerHTML + " " + surname.innerHTML;
```

I've tried many things to be able to write inside that input field, but nothing succeeds.

```
var NamePut   = document.getElementById("NamePut");
NamePut.value = Name.innerHTML;

var name    = document.getElementById(`name-${id}`);
var NamePut = document.getElementById("NamePut");
NamePut.append(name);
// document.getElementById(`NamePut`).setAttribute('value', Name);
// NamePut.value = document.getElementById(`name-${id}`).value;
```

I know a solution could be transforming it into a form, but it would change all the css style and I prefer it to solve it maintaining it like this.

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). For instance, you show code accessing elements using `document.getElementById(`name-${id}`);`, but what runs that code? What is `id`? What is the element that has the matching ID? (There are no elements shown with `id="name-___"`.)